# viewForHeaderInSection section does not displays the header

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I cannot find any texts in my Header section. This is how I set Header section:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myDataSource[section].otherKeyValues.count
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myDataSource.count
}

override  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: AccordionDetailTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AccordionDetailTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? AccordionDetailTableViewCell)!
    //        cell.headerLabel!.text = "This is a test"
    let currentCellData = myDataSource[indexPath.section]
    cell.headerLabel!.text = currentCellData.otherKeyValues[indexPath.row].key
    cell.detailLabel!.text = currentCellData.otherKeyValues[indexPath.row].value
    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

   let view: AccordionHeaderView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AccordionHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? AccordionHeaderView)!
    view.tag = section
          view.delegate = self
   view.titleLabel!.text = myDataSource[section].dateCreated == nil || myDataSource[section].dateCreated == "" ? " " : myDataSource[section].dateCreated
   return view
}
```

Items are displayed in cells and even if I set `view.titleLabel!.text = "Hello"` then Hello does not appear.

I am using `UIViewController` and implemented [FZAccordionTableView](https://github.com/fuzz-productions/FZAccordionTableView/tree/master/FZAccordionTableView)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please implement heightForHeaderInSection method of your tableView

Comment: i have implemented your view as to  UITableViewAutomaticDimension now nothing appears even cells also not seen

Comment: Give them static height for being and see if they are visible or not

Comment: Also, check constraints if you are using UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: constraints? i have implemented the UIVIewController and changes the UITable view to FZAccordion

Comment: yes thanks @Aakash giving the static height it works

Comment: @Samjhana now fix your constraints and then give UITableViewAutomaticDimension, because it is the constraint from which UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates the height of your view, if constraint are not properly implemented then it fails to calculate the correct height which is the reason your cells are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `UITableview` Delegate method like `heightForHeaderInSection`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

      return 30

}
```